# Consecutive unit tests fail, although they succeed individually

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

I have a unit test suite where every test succeeds when it is executed individually.

However, if I execute the whole suite, one test hangs when it should init a singleton. It hangs only if it is executed after a certain other unit test - if I change the order, the whole test suit executes successfully.
If I pause the execution of the hanging unit test, the stack trace is the following:
[image]

The execution hangs at the statement `static let shared = StoreManager()`:

```
class StoreManager: NSObject, CalledByDataStoreInStoreManager {
    static let shared = StoreManager() // Instantiate the singleton
// …
}
```

The other unit test that it executed before and that causes the test to hang does not use the `StoreManager` singleton.

**My question is:**
What could be the reason that the 1st test lets the initialisation of the singleton in the 2nd test fail, although this singleton is not used in the 1st test?

Comment: `swift_once` is lazy initialization of the static variable. It is trying to unlock a semaphore and hangs. That means some racing condition. Is you application multithreaded? By the way, this doesn't seem like *unit tests*, more like *integration tests*.

Comment: Thanks, Sulthan, for your comment. Yes, the app is multithreaded (a lot of async callbacks), and I have to admit that I had problems with race conditions, i.e., the app is not very well programmed. One bad idea, suggested to me earlier, was to use singletons, and I am about to get rid of them. The actual problem was (see my answer) that classes initialise singletons during their own initialisation, which created init cycle deadlocks.

Answer (score 2):

So the obvious answer is that there's a side effect occurring in your 1st test that is affecting your second test. Exactly what that side effect is, though, is dependent on two things:

- What is being tested in the first test
- What occurs in the initializer for `StoreManager`

From your description, it sounds like the first test is somehow affecting what's then used in the `StoreManager` init, which is unaffected when that test is not run before your 2nd test.

Comment: I search for such side effects, but could not find any. But your answer (+1) motivated me to look once more more carefully, and I found the problem, see my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The side effect that the answer of BHendricks pointed me to, was the following:
Since my app uses also the watch, the watch session is activated in the app delegate, as recommended by Apple.  This was done by calling a function in a `WatchSessionManager` instance, and the initialisation of this instance tried to init a singleton that is also tried to be init by the Storemanager.
This created an init cycle deadlock.

Since I use a mock app delegate for unit tests, I activate now the watch connectivity session there without initialising the unnecessary initialisation of the  `WatchSessionManager` instance, and the deadlock is avoided.